# how can select items from drop down list in telerik test studio

Tags: testing, telerik, telerik-test-studio

while am recording script am selecting items item from drop down list.But while playing back(running script) it's not identifying item from drop down list.it's giving error 
Unable to locate element. Search failed!
how can make it identifiable.

Comment: Hi - can you show us your script, and the html it's trying to act on? It's difficult to know how to help you with so little information.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error. Usually it's because the item you are selecting in the drop down is not visible, because the drop down list is long such that it has scrollbar. I have many issues with the drop down selection, however I'm recording Silverlight OOB app, so I think that it depends on your application how many issues you will run into. It's definitely not as friendly to use as Watir or Selenium...

Comment: Silverlight does this on purpose; it only loads the items needed for viewing. It is possible to force SL to load all the elements, but it can take a while. See http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/user-guide/code-samples/silverlight/radgridview/scrolling.aspx

Comment: You can also try to refresh the DOM.